# install_name_tool malformed object (load command 23 cmdsize is zero) - Mac OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, object, malformed, torch

Installation of cunn for torch on Yosemite fails with malformed object error.

```
 -- Install configuration: "Release"
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lib/libcunn.so
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lib/libcunn.so malformed object (load command 23 cmdsize is zero)
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/install_name_tool: object: /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lib/libcunn.so malformed object (load command 23 cmdsize is zero)
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lua/cunn/init.lua
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1/lua/cunn/test.lua
Updating manifest for /usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks
cunn scm-1 is now built and installed in /usr/local/ (license: BSD)
```

Searching online shows that this is related to library corruption or an update to install_name_tool. I replaced the install_name_tool from XCode(6.1) into /usr/bin but I still get the same error.  Below are some diagnostics

```
$ ls -l $(which install_name_tool)
-rwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin  14192 Nov  8 11:25 /opt/local/bin/install_name_tool

$ otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
/usr/bin/install_name_tool:
    /usr/lib/libxcselect.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1213.0.0)


$ pkgutil --file-info /usr/bin/install_name_tool
volume: /
path: /usr/bin/install_name_tool

pkgid: com.apple.pkg.Essentials
pkg-version: 10.10.0.1.1.1412852630
install-time: 1413599255
uid: 0
gid: 0
mode: 755
```

I need this to work so that I can use CUDA with torch, I have already spent hours on it, please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it by building `libcunn.so` locally.
Run the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/torch/cunn.git
ls cunn
cmake -E make_directory build
cd build/
cmake .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH="/usr/local/bin/.." -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX="/usr/local/lib/luarocks/rocks/cunn/scm-1" && make
```

Then you should have

```
Linking CXX shared module libcunn.so
```

Then just copy the library to the target folder:

```
cp libcunn.so /usr/local/lib/lua/5.1/libcunn.so
```